# c++ avoid vector<bool> instantiation

Tags: c++, templates, vector, stl

I have some class template over std::vector:

```
template<typename T>
class MyClass{
public:
    // public methods;
private:
    std::vector<T> buffer_;
    // private methods and members
};
```

This is simplified version of my class. Internal `vector` here used as a buffer for sorting, different IO operation, relying on its single memory piece implementation such as `fstreams` custom buffer and buffer size known on runtime only.
All is ok, but `vector<bool>` instantiation absolutely doesn't suitable for such purpose. I would like to have `vector<char>` or `vector<uint8_t>` instead of `vector<bool>` instantiations in my class. Also I cant use additional libraries like boost, standart library only.

Is there any workaround?

Comment: By STL, you really mean the [tag:c++-standard-library], right?

Comment: @remyabel yes, I'am. STL is only a part of standart library, you are right

Comment: @vard Why do you believe your own specialization for `std::vector<bool>` could be done better as the already available one from the c++ standard library?

Comment: He may need data, emplace and emplace_back which are not available in the vector<bool> specialization

Comment: @πάντα I just want every bool in such specialization to span 1 byte in my vector.

Comment: @vard Ah, I see now, because of the de-/serialization.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Create a helper class to determine the value type for the vector (this code uses C++11 but can easily be rewritten using only C++98):

```
template<typename T>
struct VectorValueType {
    using type = T;
};

template<>
struct VectorValueType<bool> {
    using type = char;
};

template<typename T>
using VectorValueType_t = typename VectorValueType<T>::type;

template<typename T>
class MyClass{
private:
    std::vector<VectorValueType_t<T>> buffer_;
};
```

Comment: You need a space between the two `> >`

Comment: Well, the bitwise operation on the `vector<char>` that's emplaced for `bool` template parameter, will need special handling, how is this distinguishable, selected for instantiated template code?

Comment: @galinette Not for the current standard.

Comment: You're right, I always forgot that. But the author did not specify

Comment: I use c++11 standart, its okay.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I don't quite understand, you can write `using value_type = VectorValueType_t<T>` in `MyClass` and I think it's a question more to OP what to do next with it.

Answer (score 2):

Use a wrapper subclass like so:

```
template<typename T>
struct sub_vector: public vector<T> {};

template<>
struct sub_vector<bool>: public vector<char> {};
```

And then just use that instead of `vector`.

Comment: As you go to all the trouble of wrapping `vector`, you might want to re-define the functions with the proper types. Also, you might want to forward the allocator if customized.

Answer (score -1):

Use template specialization for the T=bool type.
Then for all types except bool, vector is used.

```
template <typename T>
class MyClass
{
private:
    std::vector<T> buffer_;
};

template <>
class MyClass<bool>
{
private:
    std::vector<char> buffer_;
};
```

You need to specialize every member function that you will add, too.

Comment: Hmmm, since partial specialization isn't possible, this could become a tedious job.

Comment: vector<bool> is done like that, with full specialization. You only do the reverse job...

Comment: Wtf with the -1?? It may not be the best answer but still deserves a non negative note...

Comment: I removed my downvote after your 1st edit. Initially you received 3 including mine. It's often the case downvoters won't review the questions they have downvoted.